# How to convert data into given format?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, presto, unnest

```
task_id     json_data
task1       [ [160, "4d3a339c-68ba"], [15, "554fc01c-b5d2"] ]
```

I have to change the above image into the below format:

```
task_id     area        iiid    
task1       160         "4d3a339c-68ba"
task1        15         "554fc01c-b5d2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the json content to an array of arrays, then unnest it, and then bring the first and second element of each sub-array:

```
select t.task_id, x.ar[0] area, x.ar[1] iiid
from mytable t
cross join unnest(cast(t.json_data as array(array(varchar)))) as x(ar)
```